# Insert row Google spreadsheet

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I want to make an table with some basic information and the status of different tests. By jusing de Spreadsheet API in Java it's possible to add a row to the end of the table. But te problem is that it's better to have the last test on top of the tests. But i can't manage it to insert a row above the previeous test row. I found another question where they said thats not possible to insert but is there someone who knows how to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Spreadsheets API only allows for rows to be added to the end of a sheet.

Comment: Can you plese tell me how to add the row to Google Spread sheet using Javascript or in HTML